# asp.net page navigation history

Tags: jquery, asp.net, history

How can I implement page navigation history, like the functionality found in:

[jggrid demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

When you click on a link which opens a new page, that page name is added as a tab to the top bar. Then, you are able to go back to these pages by clicking on the added tabs; and you are also able to delete tabs.

Is there a tutorial somewhere on how this can be acheieved (or maybe a jquery plugin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to the argument below (in comments): I would argue the functionality shown on *the jqgrid site* is neither breadcrumbs nor tabs in the sense of traditional navigation.

**Breadcrumbs** traditionally follow a navigational hierarchy and reset/clear when a new section or area of the site is opened.  *The jqgrid site* does not follow that behavior.

As for **tabs**, yes they are *styled* as tabs however it is really just a persistent list of pages you have viewed.  In this case they can be closed and opened with no common link to each other.

In pseudo code, achieving this is quite simple.

**Navigation Block** (left side) - Static placeholder containing links to your various content pieces.

**Content Block** (right side) - Static placeholder for dynamic content pieces

Order of events:

1. User clicks on a **Navigation Block** item (a link)
2. Retreive the **item's content** (via ajax or pre-loaded object)
3. Display the **item's content** on a placeholder (tab in this case) within the **Content Block** (here you can use jQuery tabs or any other display item)

The placeholders (tabs) keep piling up and have nothing to do with how or where the user navigates next.  Closing one does not impact existing open items.

Here's a *really* simple example - http://jsfiddle.net/aZa9d/7/

Answer (score 0):

They're called 'breadcrumbs'. There's a [bunch](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2011/07/17/7-jquery-breadcrumbs-to-enhance-your-website-navigation/) of jQuery plugins.

Comment: Seriously? Who cares how they're displayed, it's still a breadcrumb.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how the breadcrumbs have the functionality I asked about, since they don't really keep track of the history. They just show the site hierarchy ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used Ext.Net? [Check these Tabs Panels out](http://examples.ext.net/#/TabPanel/Basic/Ajax_Load/) and you may find your solution. Good luck!